# a timeout error when connecting to mysql database(updated)

Tags: python, mysql, database, timeout, python-idle

I want to create a python program that uses a mysql database. For that I've tried to create a connection to my mysql database using the python IDLE with this line of code:

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", database="sys", host="127.0.0.0")
```

Every time I enter this code into the IDLE, it returns this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 509, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    db = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", database="sys", host="127.0.0.0")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 511, in open_connection
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.0:3306' (60 Operation timed out)
```

I work with the python 3.8 IDLE in this situation.

The same thing happens when I try it in the terminal, also running python 3.8.
*update*

I tried to solve the problem by creating a new user of the database, with an actual password. I also made sure the new user has gotten all privileges.

And then this happens in the terminal:

```
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> a = mysql.connector.connect(user="hassan", password="**********",        database="sys", host="127.0.0.1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-  packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-  packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-  packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-  packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 208, in _open_connection
    self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
  File    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-  packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 137, in _do_auth
    packet = self._protocol.make_auth(
   File  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 99, in make_auth
    packet += self._auth_response(client_flags, username, password,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 58, in _auth_response
    auth = get_auth_plugin(auth_plugin)(
  File  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- packages/mysql/connector/authentication.py", line 190, in get_auth_plugin
    raise errors.NotSupportedError(
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin     'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

Does somebody have an explanation for this?

Comment: 1) It seems to be a server problem, not a python problem. 2) Try another sql client (ie heidisql.exe) or whatever you want. Do you have the same problem? 3) What is your sql server and how do you run it or install it?
4) try to put `password = '' 'in your settings.
5) Create a user for your database with a real password.

Comment: I am fairly sure IDLE is not relevant, but to be sure, run your program from a command line without involving IDLE.

Comment: I use the basic mySQL server, version 8.0.19, downloaded from the official website of mySQL. I tried sequel pro to connect to my database, but that didn't work either, neither did option 4. I tried your last option, which is creating another user. I did create one, and I granted it the same privileges as the root user with the GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER'@'LOCALHOST' and FLUSH PRIVILEGES, but somehow, I still don't have access to my databases with my new user. Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: I tried the same from a command line and it gives the same error.